# variable transformation for percentages and zero values

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation

I am working on socio-economic factors related to opioid mortality in North Carolina.  I have three dependent variables: total age adjusted rate, white age adjusted rate, and nonwhite age adjusted rate for all opioid related deaths from 2014 to 2017.  The problem I am running into is related to the non-white age adjusted rate and one of the socio-economic variables that I am interested  in including in the regression equation.

The socioeconomic independent variables are being pulled from the American Community Survey 2013-2017.

I have my independent variables broken down into three categories based on the current literature which suggest that there is a relationship between these variables and the mortality rate..

Educational attainment: Percent of those with a high school diploma or less, percent of those 16 years and over with a associates, and bachelors.

Work Occupation: Percent of those 16 years and over working in Agriculture, forestry and mining occupations, construction occupations, service occupations, transportation and warehousing occupations. Percent of those working in manufacturing occupations.

socio-economic measures: Percent of those 18-64 years of age with a disability, percent of those living below the poverty line, median household income,

In multiple regression, the dependent variable must be normally distributed.  Both  my total age adjusted rate and white age adjusted rate are normally distributed with positive values.  The nonwhite age adjusted rate on the other hand is skewed to the left because some of the counties in NC have 0 values.  I am simply trying to find out which log transformation would be suitable for my dependent variable.  When I ran the regression analysis using the raw values, my residuals were skewed which prompted me to consider transforming my dependent variable in the first place.

My independent variable is the percent of people 16 years and over who work in occupations of agriculture, forestry, hunting, and mining.  Here is the histogram and general statistics:

PercAgrforhuntmin

[image]

```
Quantiles

100.0%  maximum 20.5
99.5%       20.5
97.5%       10.595
90.0%       6.49
75.0%   quartile    3.35
50.0%   median  2
25.0%   quartile    1.1
10.0%       0.62
2.5%        0.3
0.5%        0.2
0.0%    minimum 0.2

Summary Statistics

Mean    2.852
Std Dev 2.8866282
Std Err Mean    0.2886628
Upper 95% Mean  3.4247697
Lower 95% Mean  2.2792303
N   100
```

Here are the general stats for the variable.

[image]

```
Quantiles

100.0%  maximum 68.03839724
99.5%       68.03839724
97.5%       48.70491426325
90.0%       29.747006433
75.0%   quartile    10.0851770525
50.0%   median  3.093767162
25.0%   quartile    0
10.0%       0
2.5%        0
0.5%        0
0.0%    minimum 0

Summary Statistics

Mean    7.9664564
Std Dev 12.799374
Std Err Mean    1.2799374
Upper 95% Mean  10.50613
Lower 95% Mean  5.426783
N   100
```

I have struggled to figure out which transformation is appropriate for each variable.  I am looking to conduct OLS regression using these two variables but they are extremely skewed.

Comment: Could you give some background? Why do you think it is necessary to use any transformation at all? "Best transformation' for what purpose?

Comment: I have updated my explanation in the question.  Sorry for the misunderstanding.  I realized that the way I worded might have turned some people off.

Comment: In plain regression (OLS is an estimation method, not a model)  it's not essential that the response is normally distributed. At most it helps if error terms are approximately normal. But you have many alternatives. The main issue is that the mean response is positive in each case but some values are zero. That to me calls for a generalised linear model with logarithmic or logit link: in principle those links are quite distinct; in practice their predictions might be quite similar. But why do zeros occur in the first place? Data quality problems or just some small populations?

Comment: You are talking about 100 observations and 4 variables. That's not too many to list here for people to experiment. You should have population size too; that's likely to be an important covariate, as even though your responses are death rates, such rates are notoriously labile in small populations.

Comment: To answer the question regarding the values with zeros, it is because that is the nature of the data.  Some counties do not have values because there were no reported deaths in those counties.